# Creating an intermediate graph from XML file of UML activity diagram in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, treeview, uml, activity-diagram

I have an XML generated for an UML activity diagram. I want to generate a tree structure for XML so I could find possible transition paths. Tried with DOMXML java parser but no results. I need to group activity as nodes and transitions as edges. Also attached XML file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfsXw.jpg)Please help

**Java Code**

```
    public class DomXMLParser {

public static void main(String[] args)  throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
IOException, XPathExpressionException {
//DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
    File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Projekte/activity.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression expr 
     = xpath.compile("//xmi:XMI[xmi:type ='uml:Activity']/name/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }
```

Comment: Please post the xml as a text file

Comment: @Guenther - added the xml file. Now I need to group all categories and create tree structure. Later I would need to find different possible path trace from it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF)](https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) design to read UML models. I write a code to [Read UML Class Diagram reading with EMF](https://github.com/hammadirshad/EMF-ClassDiagram). You design you model in Enterprise Architect so [export as UMl model](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/) or design in [papyrus](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/) which build on [EMF](https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:StandardProfileL2="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701/StandardProfileL2.xmi">
<xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
<uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package"xmi:id="EAPK_263A2FE8_8346_4d1e_A851_39B9D573143D" name="Activity Model" visibility="public">
<ownedComment xmi:type="uml:Comment" xmi:id="EAID_DDCEE555_5FD6_487c_BB82_A5F055D67309" body="Case 3: Btn_Pressed = 3">
            <annotatedElement xmi:idref="EAID_367AB5AB_2A9C_4387_B4A2_2974CE57D11E"/>
        </ownedComment>
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_A165F2B1_D71E_4c10_8EB4_745B37742C0F" name="Start CnrtLk_Main()" visibility="public" isReadOnly="false" isSingleExecution="false"/>
<edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_5350396C_9C67_4190_817C_9EEF1E34582C" visibility="public" source="EAID_A165F2B1_D71E_4c10_8EB4_745B37742C0F" target="EAID_6428B619_8065_4a57_99CD_8F19CFB6F136"/> 
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_6428B619_8065_4a57_99CD_8F19CFB6F136" name="Get Parameters" visibility="public" isReadOnly="false" isSingleExecution="false"/>
<edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_A0B50908_8ADF_4507_8033_E77D777E21DD" visibility="public" source="EAID_6428B619_8065_4a57_99CD_8F19CFB6F136" target="EAID_32296133_1810_41c5_9A4D_6D3B6F11FF52"/>
<node xmi:type="uml:InitialNode" xmi:id="EAID_CF9A7618_F1C4_4395_94D5_D2F483A51119" name="System_Initial" visibility="public">
  <outgoing xmi:idref="EAID_2785D6B4_D4DF_442f_AF8B_657D85367743"/>
</node>
<node xmi:type="uml:ActivityFinalNode" xmi:id="EAID_D2EB427B_3AFD_4700_BD72_13B36684E595" name="ActivityFinal" visibility="public">
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_E036A3F5_4C88_4471_9C2F_031554144E9E"/>
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_D62F8934_F4E6_4b00_A35B_E1149E4C06E6"/>
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_CC1E7F54_9C97_4aec_AE53_55AD4DA43408"/>
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_ADD5D207_728A_4aeb_80EB_F9542CF6ED80"/>
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_873CF8C4_0192_4099_8F66_6B36FA760AB6"/>
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_6B8D52FB_C522_4bda_BE10_B5080F9F0B0D"/>
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_417A863C_D59C_4c5e_8F38_60B1DC36B077"/>
</node>
<node xmi:type="uml:DecisionNode" xmi:id="EAID_0D85B784_4393_429e_9BA1_7983BD7891CA" name="decision1" visibility="public">
                <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_1FAD9B0B_04ED_4f6a_B359_8755C3A3CA03"/>
                <outgoing xmi:idref="EAID_32A43FB9_D99D_4c3c_8382_D899FD995BA7"/>
                <outgoing xmi:idref="EAID_2FECE2AE_6CA0_48a4_82AE_D743D257F37C"/>
</node>
  </packagedElement>
</packagedElement>
```